# RegEx Help (13 length digit, ends in specific digits)

Tags: regex

Another RegEx question for a search I'm trying to do.

**The Problem**: Determine if user input is 13 digits long (numbers only) and ends with 52,56, or 57.

**My current not working solution**: `[0-9]52|56|57${13}`.  I also tried `[0-9]52|56|57{13}$` but no dice.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[0-9]{11}(52|56|57)$
```

This is what it means:

```
^          Start of string
[0-9]      Any character in 0-9
{11}       The previous token must match exactly 11 times.
(52|56|57) Alternation - any one of the possibilities must match
$          End of string
```

You could also in this case simplify it to:

```
^[0-9]{11}5[267]$
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 13 digits 11 of which can be any digit and the next two must be 52,56, or 57. 11 digits in regex notation is something like `\d{11}`. The 'or' operator is denoted by the symbole `|` so `52 or 56 or 57` becomes `52|56|57`. The resulting regex looks like `\d{11}(52|56|57)`. Parentheses are used to disambiguate.

Remember that you can construct complex regular expressions from simpler ones. This approach works always ;)